# removing duplicate objects from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been working on removing duplicate objects in an array.  I keep getting an error on trying to read the filterList[i+1].tagID.  I can manually enter the [i+1] values and get the correct results.  I'm not sure why the i+1 is an issue. I have also wondered if if it better to use a slice[i, 1] than the delete.

```js
const filterList = [{
  tagID: 1,
  tagName: "Red"
}, {
  tagID: 1,
  tagName: "Red"
}, {
  tagID: 2,
  tagName: "Orange"
}, {
  tagID: 2,
  tagName: "Orange"
}, {
  tagID: 5,
  tagName: "Blue"
}, {
  tagID: 5,
  tagName: "Blue"
}, {
  tagID: 5,
  tagName: "Blue"
}, {
  tagID: 6,
  tagName: "Indigo"
}, {
  tagID: 6,
  tagName: "Indigo"
}, {
  tagID: 7,
  tagName: "Violet"
}, {
  tagID: 7,
  tagName: "Violet"
}, {
  tagID: 7,
  tagName: "Violet"
}]

filterList.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.tagID - b.tagID;
});

for (let i = 0; i < filterList.length; i++) {
  if (filterList[i].tagId == filterList[i+1].tagID) {
    delete filterList[i];
  }
}

console.log(filterList)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Changed loop till `filterList.length - 1`
`for (let i = 0; i < filterList.length-1; i++) {
  if (filterList[i].tagId == filterList[i+1].tagID) {
    delete filterList[i];
  }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this! Using filter and es2015

```js
const filterListResult = filterList.filter((item, index, self) => index === self.findIndex((t) => (t.tagID === item.tagID && t.tagName === item.tagName)));
console.log(filterListResult);
```

```html
<script>
const filterList = [{
  tagID: 1,
  tagName: "Red"
}, {
  tagID: 1,
  tagName: "Red"
}, {
  tagID: 2,
  tagName: "Orange"
}, {
  tagID: 2,
  tagName: "Orange"
}, {
  tagID: 5,
  tagName: "Blue"
}, {
  tagID: 5,
  tagName: "Blue"
}, {
  tagID: 5,
  tagName: "Blue"
}, {
  tagID: 6,
  tagName: "Indigo"
}, {
  tagID: 6,
  tagName: "Indigo"
}, {
  tagID: 7,
  tagName: "Violet"
}, {
  tagID: 7,
  tagName: "Violet"
}, {
  tagID: 7,
  tagName: "Violet"
}]
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `set` object to remove duplicate IDs, then use `map` and `find` functions to mutate the result to give you only the first appearance of each `tagID`.

```
 Array.from(new Set(filterList.map(_=> _.tagID)))
  .map(ID=> filterList.find(o=> o.tagID === ID)));
```

```js
const filterList = [{
  tagID: 1,
  tagName: "Red"
}, {
  tagID: 1,
  tagName: "Red"
}, {
  tagID: 2,
  tagName: "Orange"
}, {
  tagID: 2,
  tagName: "Orange"
}, {
  tagID: 5,
  tagName: "Blue"
}, {
  tagID: 5,
  tagName: "Blue"
}, {
  tagID: 5,
  tagName: "Blue"
}, {
  tagID: 6,
  tagName: "Indigo"
}, {
  tagID: 6,
  tagName: "Indigo"
}, {
  tagID: 7,
  tagName: "Violet"
}, {
  tagID: 7,
  tagName: "Violet"
}, {
  tagID: 7,
  tagName: "Violet"
}]

let result = Array.from(new Set(filterList.map(_ => _.tagID))).map((ID, index) => filterList.find(o => o.tagID == ID));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could start the iteration from index `1` and check the last element with the actual element.

```js
const filterList = [{ tagID: 1, tagName: "Red" }, { tagID: 1, tagName: "Red" }, { tagID: 2, tagName: "Orange" }, { tagID: 2, tagName: "Orange" }, { tagID: 5, tagName: "Blue" }, { tagID: 5, tagName: "Blue" }, { tagID: 5, tagName: "Blue" }, { tagID: 6, tagName: "Indigo" }, { tagID: 6, tagName: "Indigo" }, { tagID: 7, tagName: "Violet" }, { tagID: 7, tagName: "Violet" }, { tagID: 7, tagName: "Violet" }]

filterList.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.tagID - b.tagID;
});

for (let i = 1; i < filterList.length; i++) {
    if (filterList[i - 1].tagId === filterList[i].tagID) {
        delete filterList[i];
    }
}

console.log(filterList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate a new list using reduce:

```
const filterList = [{ tagID: 1, tagName: "Red" }, { tagID: 1, tagName: "Red" }, { tagID: 2, tagName: "Orange" }, { tagID: 2, tagName: "Orange" }, { tagID: 5, tagName: "Blue" }, { tagID: 5, tagName: "Blue" }, { tagID: 5, tagName: "Blue" }, { tagID: 6, tagName: "Indigo" }, { tagID: 6, tagName: "Indigo" }, { tagID: 7, tagName: "Violet" }, { tagID: 7, tagName: "Violet" }, { tagID: 7, tagName: "Violet" }]

const newList = filterList.reduce((total, current) => {
    const exist = total.some(t => t.tagID === current.tagID)
    if (!exist) {
        total.push(current)
    }
    return total
}, [])
```

Comment: You lost me on "actual".  Where does this come from?

Comment: sorry I had called the current variable from actual before and forgot to replace it later